# Tkinter "Label object is not callable"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to set the text of a Tkinter label equal to the user input from an Entry object.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def Return(event):
    global Password
    global Input
    global SecurityLabel

    Password = Input.get()

    Parse(Password)
    Variations(Password)
    Search(Password)
    Additions(Password)
    Deductions(Password)
    CheckForAdjacency(ConvertToCoordinates(Password))
    MinimumRequirements(Password)

    print("Your password security rating is: " + str(Security))
    SecurityLabel['text'] = Security 

#GUI
MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.title("Password Assessor")
MainWindow.geometry("500x100")

TopMenu = Menu(MainWindow)
MainWindow.config(menu = TopMenu)

subMenu = Menu(TopMenu)
TopMenu.add_cascade(label="file", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="boop")

Label = Label(MainWindow, text="Please enter a password:")
Label.pack(fill = 'x')

SecurityLabel = Label(MainWindow, text="")
SecurityLabel.pack(fill = 'x')

Input = Entry(MainWindow, show="*")
Input.pack(fill = 'x')
Input.focus_set 

MainWindow.bind('<Return>', Return)

MainWindow.mainloop()
```

I grab the user's input when the return key is pressed from the entry box named Input with this code:

```
Password = Input.get()
```

I try to set the text of a label called SecurityLabel equal to the integer "Security" with this code:

```
SecurityLabel['text'] = Security
```

The SecurityLabel is initialized with this code:

```
SecurityLabel = Label(MainWindow, text="")
SecurityLabel.pack(fill = 'x')
```

When I try to run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/Password Assessor/Password.py", line 242, in <module>
    SecurityLabel = Label(MainWindow, text="")
TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How can I make this work? Please try to make your explanation simple.

Comment: It's because you named your variable `Label` and you're trying to call Label() again to create `SecurityLabel`, but now it's only seeing the variable and not the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Label = Label(MainWindow, text="Please enter a password:")
Label.pack(fill = 'x')
```

Naming a label "Label" created some problems. Changing the name of this label to something other than "Label' solved the error and made the other label function properly.